# electron with angular 2 having issues

Tags: angular, components, electron

**main.desktop.ts**

```
import { UniversalModule, isBrowser, isNode, REQUEST_URL, ORIGIN_URL } from 'angular2-universal';

import { App } from './app/app';


@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [ App ],
  declarations: [
    App
  ],
  imports: [
    routing,
    // Univesal module
    UniversalModule, // BrowserModule, HttpModule, and JsonpModule are included
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    App
  ]
})
```

**desktop.ts**

```
 // the polyfills must be the first thing imported
 import 'angular2-universal-polyfills';
 import 'ts-helpers';
 import './__workaround.browser.ts';

// Angular 2
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformUniversalDynamic } from 'angular2-universal/browser';
import { bootloader } from '@angularclass/bootloader';

import { load as loadWebFont } from 'webfontloader';

// enable prod for faster renders
enableProdMode();

import { MainModule } from './main.desktop';

const platformRef = platformUniversalDynamic();

// on document ready bootstrap Angular 2
export function main() {
  // Load fonts async
  // https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader#configuration
  loadWebFont({
    google: {
      families: ['Droid Sans']
    }
  });

  return platformRef.bootstrapModule(MainModule);
}

// support async tag or hmr
bootloader(main);
```

Am getting an error unable to resolve it.. Please help ..... !!! 
Is that something to do with **angular2-universal** ?

**Note:**

1.If need any other description please let me know i will provide it.
2.I am getting the following error;

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Parameter 'url' must be a string, not 
>    undefined ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError:
>   Parameter 'url' must be a string, not undefined(…) TypeError:
>   Parameter 'url' must be a string, not undefined
>       at Url.parse (url.js:90:11)
>       at urlParse (url.js:84:5)
>       at Object.urlResolve [as resolve] (url.js:422:10)

When I comment the **angular2-universal** I get;

> Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for ApplicationRef! ; Zone:
>    ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: NoProviderError Error: No
>   provider for ApplicationRef!
>       at NoProviderError.Error (native)
>       at NoProviderError.BaseError [as constructor]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by myself just changed `import { UniversalModule, isBrowser, isNode, REQUEST_URL, ORIGIN_URL } from 'angular2-universal';` to `import { UniversalModule, isBrowser, isNode } from 'angular2-universal/browser';` and add base href in my index page that is   `<base href="./">`